# Google Cloud Sql usage in external application

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to use Google Cloud Sql from external application that can't use JDBC, for example from node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use native MySQL connections to access Cloud SQL from just about anything, including, for example, node-db. See:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control

http://nodejsdb.org/